# CXXRecordDecl with child VarDecl?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I have a CXXRecordDecl with only static members, all raised to external linkage:

```
struct S {
  static constexpr int x = 10;
  static constexpr int y = 20;
  static void foo() {...}
};
```

The AST is as follow:

```
TranslatioUnitDecl 
...
CXXRecordDecl struct S definition
 -CXXRecordDecl implicit struct S
 -VarDecl x
   -IntegralLiteral 10
 -VarDecl y
   -IntegralLiteral 20
 -CXXMethodDecl foo
  ...
```

I think due to the "static" data member, there is no FieldDecl in the CXXRecordDecl, there are 2 VarDecl instead.  So how do I access the 2 VarDecl from CXXRecordDecl? There is no API function in CXXRecordDecl for that.

The only way I can think of is to use a RecursiveASTVisitor class and visit all decls.  A VarDecl has boolean API functions isStaticDataMember() and isConstexpr() to help, great! But how do I know what is the parent class for these static VarDecl?

Any suggestion will be appreciated profoundly!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer.  There is a base class DeclContext for many block decls, including RecordDecl.  This class has public member functions to iterate all the decls within the struct, look at decls_begin() and decls_end().